# Fetch value by comparing two list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Need to compare both the ids, and fetch the symptomValue and push into symptomsFormArray.

```
"partcipantData": [
    {
      "symptomId": 8651,
      "symptomValue": "N"
    },
    {
      "symptomId": 8646,
      "symptomValue": "N"
    },
    {
      "symptomId": 8642,
      "symptomValue": "N"
    }
]


var symptomsParams = [
  {
    "id": 8651,
    "value": "Abdominal pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8646,
    "value": "Chest pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8642,
    "value": "Cough"
  }
]
```

Need to compare both the ids, and fetch the symptomValue and push into symptomsFormArray.

```
 this.symptomsParams.forEach(childObj =>{
              let val = this.partcipantData.filter(obj => obj.symptomId == childObj.id)
            
              this.symptomsFormArray.push(new FormControl(val.symptomValue))
              });
```

Here the val value always return undefined, Is there any other way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to filter participant data from `symptomsParams`, you simply use array map and filter

```js
const symptomsParams = [
    {
      "symptomId": 8651,
      "symptomValue": "N"
    },
    {
      "symptomId": 8646,
      "symptomValue": "N"
    },
    {
      "symptomId": 8642,
      "symptomValue": "N"
    }
];

const partcipantData = [
  {
    "id": 8651,
    "value": "Abdominal pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8646,
    "value": "Chest pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8642,
    "value": "Cough"
  }
];

const symptomIds = symptomsParams.map(s => s.symptomId);
const filteredSymptomValues = partcipantData
  .filter(p => symptomIds.includes(p.id))
  .map(p => p.value);

console.log(filteredSymptomValues);
```

and then push it symptoms form array

```
filteredSymptomValues.forEach(value => this.symptomsFormArray.push(new FormControl(value)))
```

Comment: Index will be correct? will it cause wrong insert? .Since it doing separately. Fetching first and pushing

Comment: @user630209 it will insert according to the order of `partcipantData`

Comment: Its not necessary both the arrays will be in same order.

Comment: I am not getting you exactly, First it will filter participantData based on symptom ids symptomsParams then it will form array of values. Using this values array you can create your form array, array.filter will take care of indexing  @user630209